# JScrollPane is not Working in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have to use `JScrollPane` in my Project but it is not working.

[image]

I have pasted my code where I use a `JSCrollPane` in my main JPanel.

```
frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1179, 733);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane_1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane_1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane_1.setBounds(0, 0, 1163, 694);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane_1);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        scrollPane_1.setViewportView(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);
```

Comment: The primary cause of all your issues is `setLayout(null)` - Swing was designed around the concept of layout managers, which defines all the work for determine how child components get laid out within parent containers, all the way up the hierarchy chain. By using `null` layouts, you've rob the entire API of the ability to make determinations about how large components are and how best to react to them, especially in the case of the `JScrollPane` which uses this information to make determinations about when to show the scroll bars

Comment: So, what is the solution

Comment: Make use of appropriate layout managers based on your needs

Answer (score 2):

Setting the layout to Null means you need to handle the placement manually --> Specify the pixel location and handle the size of the container.

A layout manager handles this placement for you. The manager calculates its preferred size based on its content. The ScrollPane uses this calculated size from the layout manager.

This means you should use a layout manager, place your components within it. The rest should work automatically.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(30, 15));
    for (int row = 0; row < 30; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 15; col++) {
            panel.add(new Button("Button" + row + "/" + col));
        }
    }

    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(panel));
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which layout you are using, but you need to set your panel layout something like this

```
panel.setLayout(new FormLayout(
                        "default:grow",
                        "fill:default:grow"));
```